# Node JS Express Route Restrict issue

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to retrieve audio/image file from db.

```
app.use(restrictMiddleware());
```

Tho, because of the Route Restrict: It doesn't work.
The question is, is there any other way to retrieve audio/image file from db so that it won't conflict with Authentication Route Restriction?

```
self.get = function (req, res) {
  let params = [
    req.params.record_id,
  ];
  db.query(`SELECT * ...`, params).then((data) => {
    console.log('result: ', data.rows.length);
    res.contentType('audio/mpeg');
    res.send(data.rows[0].audiofile);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).end("Error:" + err);
  });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways of tackling this:

- Simplest way is to declare the route before you call `app.use(restrictMiddleware())`
- Cleanest way is probably go move all the secure routes into their own `Router` and only apply the `restrictMiddleware` to that, that way you can add non-secure routes easily
- Alternatively, you could check for a specific URL / Header etc in the `restrictMiddleware` and skip when appropriate (not the nicest, but would do the job)

Comment: Many thanks, in my situation I created a new Router for all the Authentication Free URL requests , and declared it before app.use(restrictMiddleware()) and works fine:)